# JQuery: toggle triggering toggle link

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a a drop down menu that uses toggle and is triggered when a + character is clicked (element with the .plusminus class). When the toggle is fired the + sign is also toggled to `display: none' whilst a - (minus) sign is toggled to display instead.

The trouble is clicking the minus sign will not trigger the drop down menu to toggle again - it only works when the + sign is showing.

Would anyone know what I have done wrong?

Thanks

```
$('#menu li:has(ul)').each(function() {   
    $(this).append( "<span class='submenuplus plusminus'> &#43; </span>" );
    $(this).append( "<span class='submenuminus plusminus'> &#45; </span>" );   
});

$('#menu').on('click','.plusminus',function() {
    $(this).prev("ul").slideToggle("slow"),
    $('.submenuminus, .submenuplus').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the click event for you. Try something like the following

```
$('#menu li:has(ul)').each(function() {   
    $(this).append( "<span class='submenuplus plusminus'> &#43; </span>" );
    $(this).append("<span class='submenuminus plusminus'> &#45; </span>");
    $(this).find('.submenuminus').hide();    
});

$('#menu .plusminus').click(function(){
    $(this).prevAll("ul").slideToggle("slow"),
    $(this).parent().find('.plusminus').toggle();
});​
```

One issue that is tripping you up is the use of

```
$(this).prev("ul")
```

This returns the nested `<ul>` for the `+` sign, but not for the `-` sign, because `.prev([selector])` only finds the **immediate** sibling matching the selector. The `<ul>` is *not* an **immediate** sibling of the `-` sign's `<span>` *(The `<span>` with the `+` sign is in between the two)*, so you must instead use `.prevAll([selector])`.

Comment: Ah thanks - I understand now. This is very close to what I need. It works but I just need a way to make it only toggle "this" .plusminus (it toggles them all otherwise). Oddly, $(this).find('.plusminus').toggle(); seems to break it